# Angular fire trying to use .Where and .OrderBy together but getting error

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have been trying all day to get this working. It works with one or the other but does not work with both of them together. It gives a console error stating that I need to create index in Firestore. However I need my data to be queried in real time, without refreshing the page. Is there any way around this? 
**Code**

```
export class PreviousOrdersComponent{
    CompletedOrders: Observable<any[]>;
    constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
      this.CompletedOrders = firestore.collection('Order', ref=>
      ref.where('orderCompleted', '==', 'true').orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're unable to create an index for a specific query ahead of time, you won't be able to perform that query.  There are no workarounds.  The index is required so that Firestore can scale properly.  Firestore refuses to perform queries that can't be supported by an index.

I suggest reading over the documentation on [managing indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).